# Git branching from an older revision and rolling back the current branch

Tags: git

I don't know Git all that well and for one of our repositories, I made a mistake.

I committed and pushed changes to a branch named "core". But then I realised that my changes should not be there - I should've created a new branch several revisions ago, say, "core-experimental".

To explain, I have:

```
A---B---C---D---E     "core"
```

But now I want to change it to

```
A---B              "core"
    \
     C---D---E     "core-experimental"
```

No one else in my team has pulled my changes yet, so any reverts I do shouldn't cause pain to anyone.

Is this possible for Git?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The other two answers work fine, but you can actually avoid having to do anything in your work tree:

```
# create core-experimental using core as starting point
git branch core-experimental core
# move core
git branch -f core <SHA1 of B>
```

This way you can do it even if you have local modifications in the work tree, and without updating a bunch of timestamps during checkout/resets which will cause you to have to rebuild (assuming this is a compiled project).

Comment: Nice, this is the kind of little extra which polishes my git-fu

Comment: I'm using doing Ruby/Python/non-compiled stuff, so I play loosey-goosey w/ file timestamps; this suggestion is better.

Comment: @Adam: Yeah, I'm never sure. Sometimes a `reset --hard` is free, sometimes in a large compiled project, the reset/checkout takes 20 seconds and forces a 10-minute compile. One other distinction: the `reset` will put in the reflogs "<commit>: updating HEAD", while the `branch -f` will put "branch: Reset to <commit>".

Answer (score 6):

```
git checkout core
git branch core-experimental
git reset --hard <SHA of B>
git push -f <remote> core
```

Or more descriptively...

1. Checkout core
2. Create the experimental branch at core's HEAD
3. Reset core's HEAD back to where you want it
4. Force a push of the update core

Comment: This worked well, even with core pushed to origin (which I had, unlike the questioner).

Answer (score 1):

In core:

```
git branch core-experimental
git reset --hard <revision-B>
```

And then:

```
git push -f
```